# Partially deserialize json into POJO but keep some raw json as field

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have a json as follows:

```
"customer": {  
     "personal": {  
        "name": “jim johnson”,  
        “miscellaneous”: {  
            “active”: “true”,  
            “addons”: {  
              "location": “us”  
            },  
        “customer_id”: “1234”   
        }    
    },  
    “source”: “main db”  
}
```

I can create an simple POJO mapping everything one to one but what I would like is the following:
I would like to have an object such as follows:

```
class Customer {  
   Personal personal;  
   String source;  
}   

class Personal {  
    String name;
    String customer_id;  
    String miscellaneous; // <—— This is the problem  
    // JsonObject miscellaneous;
}
```

How can I deserialize the json and have the `miscellaneous` kept as a string of raw json string? Or even have it as a raw json element?

Comment: As far as i understood your question, you want to have a miscellaneous property in Personal class and parse the value to it while parsing name and customer_id. right ?

Comment: How about Gson Serialized POJO class and api call with retrofit?

Comment: @AkshayKatariya: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Refer this https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/  see how POJO model are created and how retrofit is used with ConverterFactory, It can parse any level and most complicated json very easily

Comment: @Jim do you prefer to change `miscellaneous` setter or implement custom deserializer? I mean do you want yo keep all the code in your pojo or setup json to use deserializer defined in different place?

Answer (score 1):

You could set your `miscellaneous` property to a `JToken` (`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`) instead of a `String`.

```
JToken miscellaneous;
```

Once deserialized you could then access `miscellaneous.ToString()` to get the following value as a raw JSON string.

```
{  
    "active": "true",
    "addons": {
        "location": "us"
    },
    "customer_id": "1234"   
}
```

I see this post is a bit old, but I hope it helps anyone stumbling across it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class myClassName {
        public Customer customer;
        public class Customer {
            public Personal personal;
            public String source;
        }
        public class Personal {
            public String name;
           public Miscellaneous miscellaneous;
        }
        public class Miscellaneous {
            public String active;
           public Addons addons;
                   public String customerId;
        }
        public class Addons {
            public String location;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, as per your JSON `miscellaneous` isn't plain `String`.

```
    “miscellaneous”: {  
        “active”: “true”,  
        “addons”: {  
          "location": “us”  
        },  
    “customer_id”: “1234”   
    }
```

You need to write a class and declare required property for `miscellaneous`

```
   public class Miscellaneous {
       private boolean active;
       private Addons addons;
       private String customerId;
     // getter and setter
    }
```

And, then

```
String miscellaneous;
```

should be change to

```
Miscellaneous miscellaneous;
```

Comment: Yes that is what I do *not* want to do. I want to keep it raw json

Comment: why do you want that ? then you need to store it as raw JSON. Take the overhead of serializing and deserializing JSON in your code.